# chaining of several constructors c#

Tags: c#

I did some Google search but could not find anything. So I implemented something working with an intermediate constructor.

However, I am wondering whether it is possible to chain more than one constructor at the same time (base + this).

This is my current (simplified) code:

```
public BlaNode(Node Previous, Node Next) : base(Previous, Previous)
{
    this.Blas = new HashSet<BlaDiBla>();
}
public BlaNode()
    : this(null, null)
{

}
public BlaNode(Node Previous, Node Next, string Bla)
    : this(Previous, Previous)
{

}
```

Comment: Is this not working for you already?

Comment: yes it is but I may not need the intermediate constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only call one constructor at a time in a C# constructor initializer. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603.aspx) refers to only one other constructor to call, too:

> All instance constructors (...) include an invocation of **another instance constructor** (...). **The constructor** to implicitly invoke is determined by the constructor-initializer:

You can make your intermediate constructor `private` if you do not want any other code to call it.

Answer (score 1):

> Whether it is possible to chain more than one constructor at the same time (base + this)

No. You can chain either sideways (`this`), and do so multiple times, or 'up' (`base`), exactly once.

Note that the notation is closely linked to the order in which the constructor-bodies will be executed.

Your `BlaNode(Node, Node)` is the one that 'picks' the base constructor. Suppose that `BlaNode()` was allowed to select a *different* base constructor. That would only lead to confusion about which ctor(s) will be used, and with what parameters.

So there would be no gain that I can see, and there definitely would be drawbacks.

Comment: How can you chain sideways multiple times? I think that statement is incorrect as for every constructor, you can only indicate one chained constructor, be it sideways or upwards.

Comment: One time per ctor of course. But the chained ctor can chain again, as in the OPs question.

Comment: So can the ctor chained upward.

Comment: But you can only execute one `: base()` per class. And multiple `: this()`

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. You can execute as many `base()` in the constructors of one single class as you like. Sometimes, that's even kind-of a pattern: When deriving from `Exception`, it's often the most reasonable way to declare four constructors with the four [default signatures as found in the base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx), and have each of them call the respective inherited constructor with the same signature.

Comment: Ooh, that's what you're referring to. Right.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. You can use static factory methods for this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

```
private BlaNode(Node Previous, Node Next) : base(Previous, Previous)
{
    //whatever you do
}

public static BlaNode BlaNodeFactory()
{
    return new BlaNode(null, null);
}

public static BlaNode BlaNodeFactory(Node Previous, Node Next, string Bla)
{
    return new BlaNode(Previous, Previous);
}
```

Comment: They are not quite equivalent, though, as they cannot assign values to `readonly` fields.